# Google Apps Script Auto Replying

Tags: google-apps-script

I have my google voice text messages forwarding to my email for work and then sending automatic replies. I am trying to get help with line breaking the code to send the text message a little bit easier to understand.

```
function autoReplier() {
  var labelObj = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('autoreply');
  var gmailThreads;
  var messages;
  var sender;

  for (var gg = 0; gg < labelObj.getUnreadCount(); gg++) {
    gmailThreads = labelObj.getThreads()[gg];
    messages = gmailThreads.getMessages();
    for (var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii++) {

      if (messages[ii].isUnread()) {

        msg = messages[ii].getPlainBody();
        sender = messages[ii].getFrom();

        MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply","AUTOMATIC RESPONSE: Hello, Please note, I respond and can only see your messages when I am on the clock. If I am off, I will not respond. My schedule is Sunday, Monday, Wednesday-Friday from 8am-5pm. Please remember that you should be seeing your Coach or Team Lead for assistance. If you need assistance with any of the following, click on the links. ");
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The current output looks like this:

> AUTOMATIC RESPONSE: Hello, Please note, I respond and can only see your messages when I am on the clock. If I am off, I will not respond. My schedule is Sunday, Monday, Wednesday-Friday from 8am-5pm. Please remember that you should be seeing your Coach or Team Lead for assistance. If you need assistance with any of the following, click on the links.

Expected output:

> AUTOMATIC RESPONSE: Hello, Please note, I respond and can only see your messages when I am on the clock. If I am off, I will not respond.
>
> My schedule is Sunday, Monday, Wednesday-Friday from 8am-5pm.
>
> Please remember that you should be seeing your Coach or Team Lead for assistance. If you need assistance with any of the following, click on the links:

Comment: Did you try to add "\n\n" before "My schedule..." and before "Please remember..."?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n` to break lines:

```js
var message = "Line 1\n\nLine 2\n\nLine 3";

console.log(message);
```

Or you can use (`) backticks instead of normal quotes (") to keep all line breaks of your original string.

```js
var message = `Line 1

Line 2

Line 3`;

console.log(message);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Are you able to write out the code for me? I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it will not work for me.

Comment: Try to insert `\n\n` in the every place you want to have empty line.  Something like this: `"AUTOMATIC RESPONSE: Hello, Please note, I respond and can only see your messages when I am on the clock. If I am off, I will not respond.\n\nMy schedule is Sunday, Monday, Wednesday-Friday from 8am-5pm.\n\nPlease remember that you should be seeing your Coach or Team Lead for assistance. If you need assistance with any of the following, click on the links. "`